# Add Online Offline Status in Flutter App Like Whatsapp using Firebase but how i Handle without internet

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

if I turn off wifi and then close the app, didChangeAppLifecycleState() will try to set the status to 'offline' in Firestore, but as wifi is off **Firestore can't set the status to offline... So, other users of the app will see that user 'online'. How can I fix this?**

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? Did you give my answer below a try?

Comment: I will try today then let you know

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has no built-in capability to write something in the database *after* the client has disconnected. In fact, most databases don't have such a capability.

One exception is Firebase's other database: the Realtime Database, which has so-called `onDisconnect` handlers, which are delayed write instructions that you to the database when you *are* connection, and which the database then executes once it detects that the connection is gone.

You can combine the Realtime Database with Firestore as shown in the links below.

See:

- The FlutterFire documentation on [`onDisconnect` handlers](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage#offline-capabilities).
- The Firebase documentation on [building a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample) with the Realtime Database.
- The Firebase documentation on [connecting Realtime Database and Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) to get presence information into Firestore too.

Comment: So, there is no method for cloud Firestore ?

Comment: OK great, can we use firebase Functions to trigger user status automatically ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I think that's what the second bullet point in my answer links to.